# Can we keep comments and Log.e, Log.d while generating an android Signed Bundle to upload to Google Play?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Can we keep codes that we commented out for some reason, comments that describe the codes, Log.e/Log.d or should we remove all these before generating Singled Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best practice, remove Log.e, Log.d and print statement, etc... there is no issue with generating a signed bundle, if someone tries to hack your APK, in the market, we have some tools that can break the APK and get all print statements.

**For Example:**

If you print your API and Response, in this case, they know your API structure and response data, etc...

**Note:** You can add command lines, there is no issue with that.

Comment: I mean, will Google reject for keeping comments in it?

Comment: Kindly check did you mention any sensitive data or any permissions.